# How to represent dates before epoch as a UNIX timestamp

Tags: time, unix-timestamp

It occurred to me that I'm not aware of a mechanism to store dates before 1970 jan. 1 as Unix timestamps. Since that date is the Unix "epoch" this isn't much of a surprise.

But - even though it's not designed for that - I still wish to store dates in the far past in Unix format.
I need this for reasons.

So my question is: how would one go about making unix-timestamps contain "invalid" but still working dates? Would storing a negative amount of seconds work? Can we even store **negative** amounts of seconds in a unix-timestamp? I mean isn't it unsigned?

Also if I'm correct then I could only store dates as far back as `1901. dec. 13 20:45:52` could this be extended any further back in history by any means?

Comment: Unix `time_t` is a signed 32-bit int, so it can go back to 1901 as you have noted. You should check your OS, many have expanded `time_t` to 64 bits, which gives you a few hundred billion years of leeway.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is *usually* a 32-bit number of whole seconds from the first moment of 1970 in UTC, the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) being `1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC`. That means a range of about 136 years with about half on either side of the epoch. Negative numbers are earlier, zero is the epoch, and positive are later. For a signed 32-bit integer, the values range from `1901-12-13` to `2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC`.

This is not written in stone. Well, it *is* written, but in a bunch of different stones. Older ones say 32-bit, newer ones 64-bit. Some specifications says that the meaning is "implementation-defined". Some Unix systems use an unsigned int to extend only into the future past the epoch, but usual practice has been a signed number. Some use a float rather than an integer. For details, see Wikipedia article on [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), and [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5617925/642706).

So, basically, your Question makes no sense. You have to know the context of your programming language (standard C, other C, Java, etc.), environment (POSIX-compliant), particular software library, or database store, or application.

## Avoid Count-From-Epoch

Add to this lack of specificity the fact that [a couple dozen other epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) have been used by various software systems, some extremely popular and common. Examples include January 1, 1601 for NTFS file system & COBOL, January 1, 1980 for various FAT file systems, January 1, 2001 for Apple Cocoa, and January 0, 1900 for Excel & Lotus 1-2-3 spreadsheets.

Further add the fact that different granularities of count have been used. Besides whole seconds, some systems use milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds.

I recommend against tracking date-time as a count-from-epoch. Instead use specific data types where available in your programming language or database.

## ISO 8601

When data types are not available, or when exchanging data, use text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. This standard defines sensible string formats for various kinds of date-time values.

- Date

  - `2015-07-29`
- A date-time with an offset from UTC (Z is zero/[Zulu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones) for UTC) (note padding zero on offset)

  - `2015-07-29T14:59:08Z`
  - `2001-02-13T12:34:56.123+05:30`
- Week (with or without day of week)

  - `2015-W31`
  - `2015-W31-3`
- Ordinal date (day-of-year)

  - `2015-210`
- Interval

  - `"2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z"`
- Duration (format of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`)

  - `P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S` = "period of three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds"

Search StackOverflow.com for many more Questions and Answers on these topics.

Comment: Awesome, though I was afraid that it would come down to being `implementation-defined`.

Comment: Perl's `localtime` also counts from January 0, 1900, although this is referenced as an array of numbers rather than seconds since epoch

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Many different computer systems/languages/environments use [many different epoch references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing), a couple dozen.