# Serialize / Deserialize UTC DateTimes before 01-01-1970

Tags: c#, datetime, momentjs, utc

I am having the following problem. If I serialize Dates since 01-01-1970 and I deserialize them it works as expected. But for dates before 01-01-1970 the deserialization with momentjs doesn't work.

```
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(2010, 10, 20);
        DateTimeOffset dt2 = new DateTimeOffset(dt).ToUniversalTime();
        long a = dt2.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        Console.WriteLine("value1: " + a); //1287525600000 => moment(1287525600000).toDate() => Wednesday, 20. October 2010 (00:00:00)
        DateTime dtfoo = new DateTime(1962, 10, 20);
        DateTimeOffset dtfoo2 = new DateTimeOffset(dtfoo).ToUniversalTime();
        long afoo = dtfoo2.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        Console.WriteLine("value2: " + afoo); // -227239200000 => moment(-227239200000).toDate() => Friday, 19. October 1962 (23:00:00 GMT+01:00)
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I am deserializing the dates just with `moment(unixtime).toDate()`. The first date is 20-10-2010. The second date is 19-10-1962 (instead 20-10-1962).

Comment: What do you expect? Unix time is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. If you need to represent dates befor this, choose another representation.

Comment: I am getting this value 19. October 1962 (23:00:00 GMT+01:00) for the date 20. October 1962. I think, I can represent dates before 1970 with Unix time but maybe I should serialize/deserialize the date in a different way.

Comment: So you think the serializer is to blame?

Comment: I am asking if I can use unix time to represent dates before 1970.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708622/how-to-represent-dates-before-epoch-as-a-unix-timestamp